# I pressed login in smowcode app but it is not working

Tags: ide, esp32, nodemcu

When I opened smowcode app, Login button appears. When I press it, nothing happens. What should I do?

I restarted app many times but it's not working. I reinstall again but still it's not working. I also tried restarting my laptop.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ensure your default browser is selected (Eg. Chrome) & Allow third party cookies in your browser when Smowcode opens the browser on login.

1. Go to Windows Settings to change the default browser.
2. On login press on the browser, click the padlock on the left of URL and allow third party cookies to the smowcode site.